# User login using Email or Username gives null if user not found in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-3.1

I am using the default identity pages with some modifications, in the login page I included the username for the user to login. It works perfectly, the user now can login by both the email and username, but when the users enters false info, a null exception appears instead of showing

> Invalid login attempt

Code:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    //Check if user entered email or username in the Input.Email property
    var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(Input.Email) ?? await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(Input.Email);
    // user is null if not exist? error

    // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
    // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, set lockoutOnFailure: true
    var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: true);

    if (result.Succeeded)
    {
        //some code
    }
    if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
    {
        return RedirectToPage("./LoginWith2fa", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = Input.RememberMe });
    }
    if (result.IsLockedOut)
    {
        _logger.LogWarning("User account locked out.");
        return RedirectToPage("./Lockout");
    }
    else
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
        return Page();
    }
}
```

I get why the error happens, but don't know what the proper way to solve it.

Originally the `signInManager` checks the user input not the actual user, so if the input is not found it will not be succeeded, how can I do it the same old way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> when the users enters false info, a null exception appears

In source code of [`PasswordSignInAsync(TUser, String, Boolean, Boolean)` method](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/1ca039fd14d2fc1166f2c589fbc510ab315cb18b/src/Identity/Core/src/SignInManager.cs#L330), we can find it will throw NullException error if user is null.

```
public virtual async Task<SignInResult> PasswordSignInAsync(TUser user, string password,
            bool isPersistent, bool lockoutOnFailure)
        {
            if (user == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(user));
            }

            var attempt = await CheckPasswordSignInAsync(user, password, lockoutOnFailure);
            return attempt.Succeeded
                ? await SignInOrTwoFactorAsync(user, isPersistent)
                : attempt;
        }
```

> how can I do it the same old way?

You can modify the code as below to check if user is null, and set and display "Invalid login attempt." error message.

```
var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(Input.Email) ?? await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(Input.Email);

if (user == null)
{
    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
    return Page();
}

var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: true);

//...
//code logic here
```

Comment: Oh this simple! Thank you so much.